# Batch file "runs" via SCCM deployed package, but expected Task doesn't appear

Tags: sccm-2012-r2

OK, basically, I'm trying to deploy a one-time reboot task to about 100 computers using SCCM. I have a batch file which creates a Scheduled Task which is set to run another batch file which just runs shutdown.exe at a scheduled time (there's probably a cleaner way of doing it, but I'm still a relative novice when it comes to this kind of thing). The batch file itself works just fine and successfully creates the Scheduled Task when I run it manually, so it's not the problem.

However, I'm watching the execmgr.log on the two computers I'm testing this on, and when the package runs, according to the log it completes successfully (exit code 0, every single time), but the task never appears in Task Scheduler. So...I have no clue what's going on.

I have the command line of the Program set just to the .bat file (the source of the Package is set to the correct folder on the SCCM MP), Run is set to Normal, there are no requirements set,  the program is set to run Whether or not a user is logged on, with admin rights, and Runs with UNC name is chosen. Everything else is set to default.

Originally I had the contents of the batch file set as the package command line, but I thought maybe that was causing something to fail, hence how it's running now with the batch file.

Anyone have an idea how I can get this to run, or at least why it's not doing what it should be?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, this was caused by a couple of things...

First, even though the batch file was working correctly, the package wasn't due to having incorrect (for SCCM/Task Scheduler) paths in the batch file. Once I removed the full UNC path, and removed all spaces from the files names and paths (quotes around the path and filenames didn't help, since Task Scheduler seemed to ignore that when either exporting or importing the xml), everything started working correctly during testing.